# Need a php based chat script to provide website members chat functionality with visitors

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, chat

I want a chat script through which each registered member can independently chat with the visitors on the site.

What i want is something like trade manager on tradekey.

Answer (score 4):

PHP is one of the worst things you can use for that. If you want a chat, embed an AJAX-based IRC chat (qwebirc for networks like gamesurge, freenode and quakenet; mibbit for others) or if it has to be a purely web-based chat use something that actually runs a chat server daemon so it can use techniques like COMET/long-polling and doesn't have to hammer your server with requests to check if something new has been written.

Comment: I know about Ajax, its just I dont want to code from the scratch thats why i am asking for a open source script or some guide line from where i shud start. Also I will not use this script on my main server, I will setup a new server for chat.

Answer (score 1):

www.blueimp.net is Ajax open source chat.

Answer (score 0):

php has web-socket and support forking, too. it is just not that academic language!